# Unable to start server due Templates issues

Tags: django, django-templates

**hi all,
I tried to build Django page using this post: djangocentral.com/building-a-blog-application-with-django/
Seems I completed all steps but I am getting this error when running server.
Do you know what can be reason for error message I am getting?**

```html
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
index.html, blog/post_list.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Django Version: 3.2.9
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
index.html, blog/post_list.html
Exception Location: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 47, in select_template
Python Executable:  C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\mysite\\my_site',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\lib',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\Scripts',
 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python37-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django',
 'C:\\Download\\Development\\NowaStrona_Django\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 15 Dec 2021 10:54:46 +0000
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\T\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\E\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\M\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\P\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\L\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\A\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\T\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\E\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\S\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\_\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\D\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\I\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\R\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\S\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\blog\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\T\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\E\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\M\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\P\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\L\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\A\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\T\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\E\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\S\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\_\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\D\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\I\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\R\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\mysite\my_site\S\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\blog\post_list.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Download\Development\NowaStrona_Django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\blog\post_list.html (Source doe
```

I am also attaching SETTINGS file which was used:

```
  """
Django settings for my_site project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-pt0&^4*xfh$-0dmwo$n-y=h@hvelr+^wyvhha=s3=z27#cirp4'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'blog',
]  

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': 'TEMPLATES_DIRS',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I am running server locally, and also I am beginner with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template configuration is incorrect you can configure it like this

**method 1**

```
#easy and recomended  for latest version of django  
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**method 2**

you've to put your **TEMPLATES_DIRS** without single or double quotes if you put quotes than it will treated as string not a variable so change like this

```
'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIRS],
```

**Note:**
**DIRS** defines a list of directories where the engine should look for template source files, in search order.

Comment: thanks for comment! for Method1: do I also need to remove these lines from settings?: BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')

Comment: Hello @Pr0bitMarcinIdzik check i've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app called **"post"** and search for a template folder, if you cannot find it maybe you have a template folder with a subfolder call **"post"**.

Inside of it add a new file call : **post_list.html**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your template configuration is not correct

in your settings.py change this line

```
'DIRS': 'TEMPLATES_DIRS',
```

to

```
'DIRS': ['templates/'],
```